# Is there a way to monitor multiple endpoints inside a single API (App Services) in Azure Application Insights

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-appservice

The goal would be to follow each enpoint individually including those metrics :

- Number of request
- response time (request duration)
- Request failures
- Exceptions

I can do that based on the server (role) but can I do it based on each enpoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What kind of duration are you looking for? Using kusto you can create a query like this

```sql
requests
| summarize 
    requests = count(), 
    failures = countif(success == false),
    avg_duration = avg(duration)
  by operation_Name, cloud_RoleName
```

Does this help to get you started?